The images don’t show up while using html on vscode on a mac
Ive written a very basic html code that includes a img tag and a p tag.
I copied the image address from google for image and then i ran the program. But no matter which browser or live server in my macbook, the image does not show up. But when i use my windows pc, for the very same code, the image can be seen through the live server as well as when you open the localhost through browser.
I wrote a html code where the title said cat. I put an img tag in the body  where img src led to an existing image from google(not a closed site).
I was expecting the image to be seen through the live server or the browser when i run the program on my macbook. But the image is just not there only an icon

Show your code please.

Thank you so much for your interest to help.
The issue has been resolved by changing a few json settings on vs code
